# What is the difference between AudioFileOpenURL and ExtAudioFileOpenURL?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

If I use ExtAudioFile in conjunction with a remoteIO audio unit, I can use `ExtAudioFileSetProperty` with `kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat` to convert the audio format read from disk into a device native format (with canonical au tags).

It seems when I use AudioFileOpenURL and related methods I can't use `AudioFileSetProperty` with `kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat` in the same way.

Why can't I convert any audio file to the client data format through this slightly higher level api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AudioFile API came first, and is the lower-level of the two.  ExtAudioFile is essentially a wrapper around an AudioFile and an associated AudioConverter.  It is ExtAudioFile's internal AudioConverter that provides the functionality to convert to a specific client format.

Comment: Ah, so I had the lower-level / higher level the wrong way round.